# Count: Calculate amount same fruit from a specific fruit-bag(list)

Tags: c#

There's two tables. One for `Fruit` and the other for `FruitBag`. There can be many `FruitBag` containing many `Fruit`. I want to be able to calculate the amount of same fruits inside a specific fruit-bag.

```
public ActionResult FruitCheck(int fruitBagId, int fruitId)
{
    var getFruitBag = db.FruitBags.SingleOrDefault(fb => fb.Id == fruitBagId);

    int Amount = getFruitBag.// check amount same fruit-id inside current FruitBag
    ....
}
```

This following code wont work, but it's about what I had in mind so you get an idea what I mean:

```
int Amount = getFruitBag.Count(c=> c.Fruit.Where(f=> f.Id == fruitId))
```

---

```
  public partial class FruitBag {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public FruitBag() {
            this.Fruits = new HashSet<Fruit>();
        }
        public System.Guid Id { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
public partial class Fruit {
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Fruit() {
        this.FruitBags = new HashSet<FruitBag>();
    }

    public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<FruitBag> FruitBags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok, you are asking basically one and the same question twice, so apparently you have an issue. I'm pretty sure it can easily be solved if you post the `FruitBag` and `Fruit` classes.

Comment: @IvanStoev I formulated my last question wrong, where fruitBag wasn't specified, which results it count fruits from ALL fruitBags.

Comment: I personally have no problem with that. Still we need your class, otherwise all you get is a guesswork.

Comment: @IvanStoev I added my classes. Sorry I somehow overlooked the last sentence about adding classes. :)

Comment: Thank you. So what was the issue with `db.FruitBag.Where(fb => fb.Id == fruitBagId).Sum(fb => fb.Fruits.Count(f => f.ID == fruitId))`?

Comment: @IvanStoev Not sure, I just get value 1 every time, no matter how many of same fruit was in FruitBag

Comment: Actually looking at your entity model, it's a `many-to-many` relationship with implicit junction table maintained by EF for you, in which case the combination of the `FruitBagID` and `FruitID` will be unique (EF will set that as composite PK), so there is no way you can enter one and the same `Fruit` more than once for a specific `FruitBag`. So something is wrong with either the question or the model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var amount = getFruitBag.Fruit.
      GroupBy(x => x.Id).
      Select(x => new { x.Key, Value = x.Count() }).ToList();
```

You'll get an anonymous type with all fruits and their counts.

Comment: it's not working. It calculate amount different `fruits` if I replace `ToList` to `Count`. I just want int-value, no a list.